# how to get set fixed colors in array iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, colors

Hi I tried random color but need static color each time

```
 CGFloat red = arc4random() % 255 / 255.0;
    CGFloat green = arc4random() % 255 / 255.0;
    CGFloat blue = arc4random() % 255 / 255.0;
    UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithRed:red green:green blue:blue alpha:1.0];
    NSLog(@"%@", color);
```

Thanks

Comment: store your color at globally to use once generated

Comment: You can set the static color in info.plist

Comment: @Dev_Tandel  How to get this in loop or something

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking for. You say you want "random", and "static color each time," and then in the comments "How to get this in loop or something". What is the end result you want? An array of random colors?

Comment: Also, do you want a Swift answer or Objective-C? Your tags make it unclear and so there have been answers given for both.

Comment: Calm ad try to explain what you want . Your requirement

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a singleton to access and generate color.
I created a example, `RandomizeColor` class is a singleton.

`RandomizeColor.h`:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface RandomizeColor : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIColor *currentColor;

+ (instancetype)sharedInstance;

- (void)generate;

@end
```

`RandomizeColor.m`:

```
#import "RandomizeColor.h"

@implementation RandomizeColor

+ (instancetype)sharedInstance
{
    static RandomizeColor *sharedInstance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[RandomizeColor alloc] init];
        sharedInstance.currentColor = UIColor.blackColor;
    });
    return sharedInstance;
}

- (void)generate
{
    CGFloat red = arc4random() % 255 / 255.0;
    CGFloat green = arc4random() % 255 / 255.0;
    CGFloat blue = arc4random() % 255 / 255.0;
    UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithRed:red green:green blue:blue alpha:1.0];

    self.currentColor = color;

    NSLog(@"%@", color);
}

@end
```

When you need to access this color, just `#import "RandomizeColor.h"` and call `RandomizeColor.sharedInstance.currentColor;` default is black color.

And if you want to generate a new random color, call `RandomizeColor.sharedInstance.generate;`

Answer (score 0):

Try like this first create a plist file  color.plist

[image]

Make one function for get the color array from info.plist

```
func fetchColorDataArray()->[String]{

    if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "color", ofType: "plist") {
        if let color = NSArray(contentsOfFile: path) {
            return color as! [String]

        }
    }
    return []
}
```

And you can call this method

```
var colorArray = [String]()
colorArray = self.fetchColorDataArray()
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an extension of `UIColor` this way:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

extension UIColor{
    class func colorFromRGB(_ r: Int, g: Int, b: Int) -> UIColor {
        return UIColor(red: CGFloat(Float(r) / 255), green: CGFloat(Float(g) / 255), blue: CGFloat(Float(b) / 255), alpha: 1)
    }

    class func palette() -> [UIColor]{
        let palette = [
            UIColor.colorFromRGB(85, g: 0, b: 255),
            UIColor.colorFromRGB(170, g: 0, b: 170),
            UIColor.colorFromRGB(85, g: 170, b: 85),
            UIColor.colorFromRGB(0, g: 85, b: 0),

            UIColor.colorFromRGB(255, g: 170, b: 0),
            UIColor.colorFromRGB(255, g: 255, b: 0),
            UIColor.colorFromRGB(255, g: 85, b: 0),
            UIColor.colorFromRGB(0, g: 85, b: 85),

            UIColor.colorFromRGB(0, g: 85, b: 255),
            UIColor.colorFromRGB(170, g: 170, b: 255),
            UIColor.colorFromRGB(85, g: 0, b: 0),
            UIColor.colorFromRGB(170, g: 85, b: 85),

            UIColor.colorFromRGB(170, g: 255, b: 0),
            UIColor.colorFromRGB(85, g: 170, b: 255),
            UIColor.colorFromRGB(0, g: 170, b: 170), 
            UIColor.colorFromRGB(0, g: 139, b: 210)
        ]
        return palette
    } 
}
```

And to fetch the array of UIColors, use this:

```
let colors = UIColor.palette()
```